# webpack-dev-middleware serving bundle on different port than app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webpack, webpack-dev-middleware

I've been working on a React boilerplate that harnesses Apollo-Client and GraphQL. My app is set up so that I have one node process running an Express server on port 3000 that actually renders the application, and another Express server on port 3001 that uses `webpack-dev-middleware` to package and serve my JavaScript bundle.

I was getting a 404 when trying to load my bundle using `<script src="/static/js/bundle.js />`, because it was trying to request the bundle at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js instead of http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js, where it was actually being served by `webpack-dev-middleware`.

Is there a way to configure `webpack-dev-middleware` or my app server so that my app can access the JS bundle from `/static/js/bundle.js` without having to prepend the http://localhost:3001 in front of it?

Comment: Why do you have two separate Express servers to begin with?

Comment: One to perform server-side (pre)rendering and the other is simply for development purposes, and is not used in production.

Comment: I use one Express server for both, myself (loading the Webpack middleware only when not in production).

Answer (score 0):

You need to proxy requests from `:3000/static/js/bundle.js` to `:3001/static/js/bundle.js`, which you could do with something like this:

```
const request = require('request');
...
app.get('/static/js/bundle.js', (req, res) => {
  req.pipe(request.get('http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js')).pipe(res);
});
```

You have make sure that this route is only added during development.